# Rescuing an invalid date in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rescue

I have this in a controller:

```
pickuptime = params[:appointment][:pickuptime]
pickuptime = DateTime.strptime(pickuptime, "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p %Z")
```

I would like to `rescue` it if `DateTime.strptime` kicks back an `Invalid Date` error and redirect it back to the previous page with the flash message 'Invalid date'. How can I accomplish this?

I am using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do this in your controller:

```
begin
  pickuptime = params[:appointment][:pickuptime]
  pickuptime = DateTime.strptime(pickuptime, "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p %Z")
rescue ArgumentError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to :back
  return
end
```

The `Invalid Date` Error should be a ArgumentError exception with the message you want.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I had to change was to add a `return` after the `redirect_to :back`.